# Appropriate decimal places and significant digits for baseline characteristics table in medical journal

Tags: reporting

I have read the guidelines written by [Cole](https://adc.bmj.com/content/100/7/608) regarding the use of decimal places and significant digits when reporting in a medical journal. However, after reading the report, some matters are still unclear to me. I am busy writing a baseline table for an abstract submission in a medical journal.

I have several variables, where I am comparing the characteristics of males with females.
Right now I have the following:

- For age, I am using one decimal digit: 49.7 (SD = 12.5) vs. 47.8 (SD = 11.9). I think this is correct, because it clearly shows the difference between the two, no decimal places might obscure the difference.
- For fulfilment of classification criteria, I used no decimal place: 94% vs. 97%; according to Cole, when there is upperband of 100%, I should use 1 decimal point. Do you agree?
- Disease duration was measured in years in the raw data (=whole numbers). However, right now I have median 4.0 [IQR 1.0, 10.0] vs. 4.0 [1.0, 10.0]), so 1 decimal places for all, in light of large sample sizes. But I wonder if I should be using only one decimal number, e.g. 4 [1, 10] or even 4 [1.0, 10.0] since IQR is a statistical calculation?
- A disease activity measurement which runs 0-100, I reported as 32 (SD 16.4) vs. 29 (SD 16.2); however, I wonder if I should do 32 (SD 16) vs. 29 (SD 16). There is no clear answer in Cole's paper regarding this matter.
- Similary, a patient reported outcome (unit mm) runs 0-100; I have now 61 (SD 22.5) vs. 55 (SD 23.1). I wonder if the SD should be rounded off here too.

Would like to hear advice on the matter. It is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are reporting percentages make sure people can retrieve the absolute frequencies accurately. If the sample size is 1000 then 94% does not do that. Or report the absolute frequencies of course.

Comment: What does this particular journal expect?

Comment: There are two standards in conflict here. One runs that extraordinary detail  is no use statistically or scientifically, so rounding often does no harm and may even clarify. The other is how far readers can check what you've done or even do calculations themselves on your data or with your results. Much depends on whether the dataset will be independently available to readers. Medical statistics understandably appears more circumspect about that -- because of confidentiality concerns -- than some other branches of statistical science.

Comment: @mdewey that is a good point, however, I don't expect a classification criteria to be used in a "future calculation" (e.g. meta-analysis) so I wonder how relevent it is that the absolute frequencies are retrievable. In addition, there are many missings, which are not required to submit for abstract, so even with a decimal place, they would not know the absolute number.

Comment: @Dave I checked their [guidelines](https://ard.bmj.com/pages/authors/#submission_guidelines) and they only say `"Avoid excessive precision in scaling in order to avoid cluttering the table"`

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the comment. Agree that it is a difficult balance, which is why I am asking advice from experts. The data will not be available for public, as you mentioned, because of confidentiality concerns.

Comment: I can see good reasons here to give answers with one decimal place as you have done. _Always_ report sample sizes along with percentages and proportions; you can't know what your readers may need. // However, different journals have different 'styles' for how many places of accuracy to give, and (within reason) it is a good idea not to argue with changes suggested by the editor.

Comment: @BruceET the problem here is that if I give absolute numbers for classification criteria, I have to do the same for country of residance (13 countries) and all other categorical variables. This will increase the input data of the table significantly and reduce readibility. Readibility is also very important. If the editor wants the absolute numbers, I will add them. Thanks for your advice.